# Providing TCode to SAP SQ01 query-generated program

Tags: sap-query

There is a client-specific query (`SQ01`) in all three clients, DEVELOPMENT, QUALITY and PRODUCTION. The query is exactly same in QUALITY and PRODUCTION clients. But there are some changes in DEVELOPMENT client. I have to create a new transaction code and put the query generated report under that TCode. The name of the query-generated program is same in all the clients.

My question is, if I create a TCode in DEVELOPMENT client, put the query-generated report under it, and move this to QUALITY, then the changes of DEVELOPMENT client query report will change the query-generated report of QUALITY client or not?

If yes, then suggest some other way of creating a TCode and putting the query-generated report under it. I want the query report under the TCode as it is in QUALITY and PRODUCTION.

Comment: In one system, client-specific queries (i.e. part of the "standard area") are assigned a different report name, with name pattern `AQxx_usergroup_query` where `xx` varies depending on the client number. Why do you say "The name of the query-generated program is same in all the clients"?

Comment: NB: I guess you are talking about 3 different systems, each having a client with the same number (e.g. `050`) where the query runs, and this query is the same because it's transported (deployed) hence it has same name (e.g. `ZQ1`), same user group (e.g. `ZUG1`) and consequently its generated program has the same name (e.g. `AQ50ZUG1=====ZQ1===========`).

Comment: yes, the query name is same in all three systems - Dev, Quality and Production. and the query is exactly  same in Quality and Production. But in Development the Query lacks one Table, in the infoset, usergroup . so iam afraid if i put the query report under a tcode in Dev and moved it to quality then it will change the Query in Quality, and then the query in quality will also lack that one table.

Answer (score 2):

By creating a transaciton code for an ABAP Query, a different approach has to be followed:

Start SE93, enter the transaction code, a description and choose "Transaction with parameters..." (the last option).

[image]

The transaction has to be: "START_REPORT" and select the checkbock "Skip initial screen"

[image]

Scroll to the bottom and three parameters have to be entered. The first one is:
Name: D_SREPOVARI-REPORTTYPE
Value: AQ

[image]

And then the name and the user group from your query have to be entered:
Name: D_SREPOVARI-REPORT
Value: The user group from SQ03
and
Name: D_SREPOVARI-EXTDREPORT
Value: Query name from SQ01

[image]

Following this approach, the query will be executed correctly in all systems (DEV, QUALITY, PROD), despite the different names of the program behind the query.

Comment: What to name the package ? because there is no package name in the attributes of the report generated by sq01 query

Comment: @NiteshBakshi the package is the package of the transaction code, name it as you wish.